# sql query to sum of same id but different value?

Tags: mysql, sql

sql query to sum of  same id but different value??....
I am trying to calculate sum of same id...following is my table

```
id        barter_value
2           50,000
2           1,50,000
3           47,000
3           55,000
3           50,00,000
```

I want output like

```
id       barter_value
2          2,00,000
3          51,00,2000


select a.buyer_id, 
       a.prod_barter_val 
       from add_to_cart as a
       join(select buyer_id, 
            sum(prod_barter_val) as total 
            from add_to_cart group by buyer_id) as b 
            on a.buyer_id = b.buyer_id;
```

Comment: What is a value 1,50,000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do like:

`select buyer_id, sum(prod_barter_val) from add_to_cart group by buyer_id`

Comment: select buyer_id, sum(prod_barter_val) as total
from add_to_cart
group by buyer_id; It gives the wrong result

Comment: Id 2 gives 51 and Id 3 gives 152

Comment: @S.Patil Interesting. Are those the raw values (numbers) from DB in your question? I think your digit grouping is a little off.

Comment: it doe's 50+1 and 55+50+47 ... What is your barterVal format ? What is "," ? Why not storing this as an int 50000, 150000 ?

Comment: SUM can work with valid number, if you store it as an INT/FLOAT this code will works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, just change the sql statment (`b.total`):

```
select buyer_id, 
   sum(prod_barter_val) as total 
   from add_to_cart
   group by buyer_id
```

Comment: Why is a JOIN and implicit table needed here?

Comment: In fact it isn't. I've removed it.

Comment: This updated solution also has a problem. Aggregate function like SUM will not work without GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, SUM(barter_value) as 'total' FROM table GROUP BY id
```

What this does:
Selects all the ID's and the barter values from the table.  Then the GROUP BY takes effect, and all ID's that are equal are joined into one row.

Without the SUM you would end up with just a random value in the barter_value column, but with SUM it adds all the rows together for the ID's (seperately) and puts that in the total column.